# retrieving data from lmdb in python is throwing error

Tags: python, lmdb

This is how the dataset was created

```
def createDataset1(
  outputPath, 
  imagePathList, 
  labelList, 
  lexiconList=None, 
  validset_percent=10,
  testset_percent=0,
  random_seed=1111,
  checkValid=True,
  
  ):
  """
  Create LMDB dataset for CRNN training.
  ARGS:
      outputPath    : LMDB output path
      imagePathList : list of image path
      labelList     : list of corresponding groundtruth texts
      lexiconList   : (optional) list of lexicon lists
      checkValid    : if true, check the validity of every image
  """

  train_path = os.path.join(outputPath, "training", "9M")
  valid_path = os.path.join(outputPath, "validation", "9M")
  # CAUTION: if train_path (lmdb) already exists, this function add dataset
    # into it. so remove former one and re-create lmdb.
  if os.path.exists(train_path):
      os.system(f"rm -r {train_path}")

  if os.path.exists(valid_path):
      os.system(f"rm -r {valid_path}")
  
  os.makedirs(train_path, exist_ok=True)
  os.makedirs(valid_path, exist_ok=True)
  gt_train_path = gt_file.replace(".txt", "_train.txt")
  gt_valid_path = gt_file.replace(".txt", "_valid.txt")
  data_log = open(gt_train_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")

  if testset_percent != 0:

    test_path = os.path.join(outputPath, "evaluation", dataset_name)
    if os.path.exists(test_path):
      os.system(f"rm -r {test_path}")
    os.makedirs(test_path, exist_ok=True)
    gt_test_path = gtFile.replace(".txt", "_test.txt")



  assert(len(imagePathList) == len(labelList))
  nSamples = len(imagePathList)

  num_valid_dataset = int(nSamples * validset_percent / 100.0)
  num_test_dataset = int(nSamples * testset_percent / 100.0)
  num_train_dataset = nSamples - num_valid_dataset - num_test_dataset

  print("validation datasets: ",num_valid_dataset,"\n", "test datasets: ", num_test_dataset, " \n training datasets: ", num_train_dataset)

  env = lmdb.open(outputPath, map_size=1099511627776)
  cache = {}
  cnt = 1

  random.seed(random_seed)
  random.shuffle(imagePathList)

  for i in tqdm(range(nSamples)):
    data_log.write(imagePathList[i])
    imagePath = imagePathList[i]
    label = labelList[i]
    if len(label) == 0:
      continue
    if not os.path.exists(imagePath):
      print('%s does not exist' % imagePath)
      continue
    with open(imagePath, 'rb') as f:
      imageBin = f.read()
    if checkValid:
      if not checkImageIsValid(imageBin):
        print('%s is not a valid image' % imagePath)
        continue
    embed_vec = fasttext_model[label]
    imageKey = 'image-%09d' % cnt
    labelKey = 'label-%09d' % cnt
    embedKey = 'embed-%09d' % cnt
    cache[imageKey] = imageBin
    cache[labelKey] = label.encode()
    cache[embedKey] = ' '.join(str(v) for v in embed_vec.tolist()).encode()
    if lexiconList:
      lexiconKey = 'lexicon-%09d' % cnt
      cache[lexiconKey] = ' '.join(lexiconList[i])
    if cnt % 1000 == 0:
      writeCache(env, cache)
      cache = {}
      print('Written %d / %d' % (cnt, nSamples))
    

    #finish train dataset and start validation dataset
    if i + 1 ==  num_train_dataset:
      print(f"# Train dataset: {num_train_dataset} is finished")
      cache["num-samples".encode()] = str(num_train_dataset).encode()
      writeCache(env, cache)
      data_log.close()


      #start validation set
      env = lmdb.open(valid_path, map_size=30 * 2 ** 30)
      cache = {}
      cnt = 0
      data_log = open(gt_valid_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")
    
    # Finish train/valid dataset and Start test dataset
    if (i + 1 == num_train_dataset + num_valid_dataset) and num_test_dataset != 0:
        print(f"# Valid dataset: {num_valid_dataset} is finished")
        cache["num-samples".encode()] = str(num_valid_dataset).encode()
        writeCache(env, cache)
        data_log.close()

        # start test set
        env = lmdb.open(test_path, map_size=30 * 2 ** 30)
        cache = {}
        cnt = 0  # not 1 at this time
        data_log = open(gt_test_path, "w", encoding="utf-8")


    cnt += 1

  if testset_percent == 0:
      cache["num-samples".encode()] = str(num_valid_dataset).encode()
      writeCache(env, cache)
      print(f"# Valid datast: {num_valid_dataset} is finished")
  else:
      cache["num-samples".encode()] = str(num_test_dataset).encode()
      writeCache(env, cache)
      print(f"# Test datast: {num_test_dataset} is finished")
```

This is how i am trying to retrieve the data

```
class LmdbDataset(data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self, root, voc_type, max_len, num_samples, transform=None):
    super(LmdbDataset, self).__init__()

    if global_args.run_on_remote:
      dataset_name = os.path.basename(root)
      data_cache_url = "/cache/%s" % dataset_name
      if not os.path.exists(data_cache_url):
        os.makedirs(data_cache_url)
      if mox.file.exists(root):
        mox.file.copy_parallel(root, data_cache_url)
      else:
        raise ValueError("%s not exists!" % root)
      
      self.env = lmdb.open(data_cache_url, max_readers=32, readonly=True)
    else:
      self.env = lmdb.open(root, max_readers=32, readonly=True)

    assert self.env is not None, "cannot create lmdb from %s" % root
    self.txn = self.env.begin()

    self.voc_type = voc_type
    self.transform = transform
    self.max_len = max_len
    # nums = b"num-samples"  
    # print('NUM SAMPLES ------ \n',nums)
    nSamples = self.txn.get('num-samples'.encode())
    print("STRING nSamples :", nSamples)
    self.nSamples = int(self.txn.get(b"num-samples"))
    self.nSamples = min(self.nSamples, num_samples)

    assert voc_type in ['LOWERCASE', 'ALLCASES', 'ALLCASES_SYMBOLS']
    self.EOS = 'EOS'
    self.PADDING = 'PADDING'
    self.UNKNOWN = 'UNKNOWN'
    self.voc = get_vocabulary(voc_type, EOS=self.EOS, PADDING=self.PADDING, UNKNOWN=self.UNKNOWN)
    self.char2id = dict(zip(self.voc, range(len(self.voc))))
    self.id2char = dict(zip(range(len(self.voc)), self.voc))

    self.rec_num_classes = len(self.voc)
    self.lowercase = (voc_type == 'LOWERCASE')
```

I am getting the error below whenever the code tries to call elf.txn.get(b"num-samples")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 268, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 157, in main
    train_dataset, train_loader = get_data_lmdb(args.synthetic_train_data_dir, args.voc_type, args.max_len, args.num_train,
  File "main.py", line 66, in get_data_lmdb
    dataset_list.append(LmdbDataset(data_dir_, voc_type, max_len, num_samples))
  File "/Users/SEED/lib/datasets/dataset.py", line 189, in __init__
    self.nSamples = int(self.txn.get(b"num-samples"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I have tried many different suggestions online and some stackoverflow threads but could not figure out what is wrong.

What is causing this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: You printed the value of `nSamples`.  What value did you see?  The implication is that the value does not exist.

Comment: The error tells you `self.txn.get(b"num-samples")` is `None`. It's your job to figure out why. Work backwards from the point of the error, and print values or [step through using a debugger](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) if you have to. Dumping your code here and asking people to debug it is [off-topic](/help/off-topic) here. If you want help, please condense your code down to a [**minimal** reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is dense, convoluted and hard to follow the flow of data. It mixes lots of computation with IO, side effects, and even system calls (`os.system(f"rm -r {test_path}")`, you should use [shutil.rmtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) instead for example).

Try breaking up each action that you wish to perform so that it primarily does one specific thing:

- logical operations but no side effects
- input (read from file or network)
- output (write to file, generate a result)
- file system operations/cleanup

At each stage, you should perform verifications, and use the [rule of least power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_least_power). If you expect `self.txn` to always have 'num-samples`, then you should use` self.txn[b'num-samples']`rather`.get`, which defaults to` None`. This makes it easier to catch errors earlier in the chain.

Also I have no idea what the `lmbd` module is. Is that a library, or another file in your codebase? You should link to any libraries you are using if they aren't well known. I see several python packages pertaining to lmbd.

Answer (score 0):

From the code example, I can dissect for you. May be it will help you to close the issue.

The log says..

```
self.nSamples = int(self.txn.get(b"num-samples"))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

self.txn should be a dictionary to use get method there. As you are trying to get it, there can be two scenarios

1. num-samples can be '' in the data means there is no value
2. there is no variable called num-samples in the data.

Both of them can cause a NoneType which cannot be handled by type conversion(to int). So, you have to check whether that field is present in the data or not, by using self.txn.keys() and see if that key is present

Furthermore, if

```
 self.nSamples = int(self.txn.get(b"num-samples"))
```

is failing and not the above statement

```
 nSamples = self.txn.get('num-samples'.encode())
```

then you can simply decode the variable and use it there

like

```
   Samples =  nSamples.decode("utf-8") 
   try:
       int_samples = int(Samples)
   except TypeError:
       print(Samples)
```